# How to fix syntax issues in Java?

Tags: java

Hi I am very new to java world. I am trying to write some programs in java. I am using java online editor tools. Below program I wrote and I am trying to run but In between I started to get compilation issues.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.PriorityQueue;

import java.util.Queue;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myMethod();
    }
    static void myMethod()
    {
        int[] arrival2 = new int[] {3, 1, 3, 5};

        int[] duration2 = new int[] {3, 2, 2, 2};

        int[][] events = new int[arrival2.length][2];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrival2.length; i++) {

        events[i] = new int[] {arrival2[i], arrival2[i] + duration2[i]};

        }

        Arrays.sort(events,(a,b)->(a[1]-b[1]));

        Queue<int[]> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> a[1] - b[1]);

        int[] first = events[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < events.length; i++) {

        int[] cur = events[i];

        if (cur[0] < first[1])

            minHeap.offer(cur);

        else {
            first[1] = events[i][1];

        }
        }

    System.out.println(arrival2.length - minHeap.size());   
    }
}
```

Above code is throwing below error.

```
Solution.java:26: error: ')' expected
        Arrays.sort(events,(a,b)->(a[1]-b[1]));
                             ^
Solution.java:26: error: illegal start of expression
        Arrays.sort(events,(a,b)->(a[1]-b[1]));
                                 ^
Solution.java:26: error: ';' expected
        Arrays.sort(events,(a,b)->(a[1]-b[1]));
                                             ^
Solution.java:28: error: ')' expected
        Queue<int[]> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> a[1] - b[1]);
                                                     ^
Solution.java:28: error: illegal start of expression
        Queue<int[]> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> a[1] - b[1]);
                                                           ^
Solution.java:28: error: ';' expected
        Queue<int[]> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> a[1] - b[1]);
                                                                        ^
6 errors
```

Below is screen shot.

[image]
Can someone help me to fix this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This code passed compilation. Perhaps you are compiling it with an old Java version (pre Java 8).

Comment: I am using java 7

Comment: Well, you can't use lambda expressions in Java 7.

Comment: Okay which version we need to use then?

Comment: Java 8 or later.

Comment: I am starting java 8 in hacker rank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your IDE is a point to java version less than 8. and you are using Java 8.

As I can see the output is 3 of your code and it compiles fine.
Check your Java version.
Use java 8 version

https://dzone.com/articles/add-java-8-support-eclipse

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

[image]

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;
public class Solution {   
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        myMethod();
    }
    static void myMethod() {
        int[] arrival2 = new int[] { 3, 1, 3, 5 };
        int[] duration2 = new int[] { 3, 2, 2, 2 };
        int[][] events = new int[arrival2.length][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrival2.length; i++) {
            events[i] = new int[] { arrival2[i], arrival2[i] + duration2[i] };
        }
        Arrays.sort(events, (a, b) -> (a[1] - b[1]));
        Queue<int[]> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> a[1] - b[1]);
        int[] first = events[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < events.length; i++) {
            int[] cur = events[i];
            if (cur[0] < first[1])
                minHeap.offer(cur);
            else {
                first[1] = events[i][1];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(arrival2.length - minHeap.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed to java 8 and compiled. Now only three errors I am getting. 1. Solution.java:26: error: ')' expected
        Arrays.sort(events(a,b)->(a[1]-b[1])); 2. Solution.java:26: error: not a statement
        Arrays.sort(events(a,b)->(a[1]-b[1])); 3. Solution.java:26: error: ';' expected
        Arrays.sort(events(a,b)->(a[1]-b[1]));

Comment: which IDE you are using. share the screenshot of java config

Comment: I have added screen shot in the above question. I am taking hacker rank practice exam.

Comment: Add these import statements 
import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.PriorityQueue;

import java.util.Queue;

Comment: check out the updated answer now

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I know what was the issue?